# php fake referrer multi redirect

Tags: php, redirect

I'm using this code to hide my traffic source, it works great but it has only 1 value, how to edit code to support multi value?

E.g.:

index.php?mn=1 => affiliateurl-1.com

index.php?mn=2 => affiliateurl-2.com

index.php?mn=3 => affiliateurl-3.com

index.php?mn=4 => affiliateurl-4.com

```
<?php

$magic_number = 1; // Any number you choose except ZERO!

$affiliate_url = 'http://www.affiliateurl.com/';

$PHP_SELF = preg_replace( "/index.php/", "", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );

if (isset($_GET['mn']) && $_GET['mn']==$magic_number){      

echo '<html><head><META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"></head><body><form action="' . 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$PHP_SELF. '" method="post" id="form1">

<input type="hidden"  name="mn" value="' . $magic_number . '" /></form>

<script language="JavaScript"> 
document.getElementById(\'form1\').submit();</script></body></html>';
    return true; 
    exit();
}

if ($_POST['mn']==$magic_number){       

echo '<html><head><META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"></head><body><form action="' . 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$PHP_SELF. '" method="post" id="form1">

<input type="hidden"  name="mn" value="' . $magic_number . $magic_number . '" /></form>

<script language="JavaScript"> 
document.getElementById(\'form1\').submit();</script></body></html>';
    return true; 
    exit();
}   

$dom = preg_replace( "/^www\./", "", $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] ) ;
$ref= $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

if (((strpos($ref, $dom)!=FALSE) || (trim($ref)=="" ) ) && (!isset($_GET['mn']))  && ($_POST['mn']==$magic_number.$magic_number)){
    header( 'Location: ' . $affiliate_url);
    exit();
}

?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "support multi value"? You can only redirect to one URL from a source URL.

Comment: Is there a solution to redirect from one source URL to multi affiliate URL by using different $magic_number?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
if (isset($_GET['mn']) && $_GET['mn']==0){ 
  // some code here
}elseif(isset($_GET['mn']) && $_GET['mn']==1){
 //some code here
}else{
 //default action here 
}
```

you can use any number **elseif** that you need